# Having trouble with hiding a template sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I've been trying to set up the Workbook_Open() sub so that it hides my template sheet when I open the workbook, but it always hides the template and any subsequent sheet that I create with my macros that use the template.  I'm not really sure why it's hiding everything, but I would like to know how to hide

Comment: Show your code - otherwise we're just guessing what the problem is.

Comment: Not doing anything complex I thought. "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Visible = xlSheetHidden" It hides the template fine but when I run the separate macros to create new sheets each new sheet is hidden.

Comment: If you copy a hidden sheet then the copy doesn't automatically become visible: you have to unhide it.

Comment: Quick man. :) I think I was about to this point too. I was thinking of unhiding the template then rehiding it in the macro for the individual sheets, but I guess it would cut things down to just tell it to unhide the individual sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, your sheet create macro is making a copy of the template. Unhide the copy:

```
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy
sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
```

Comment: I think this is what Tim was referring to. What I was thinking was a little less efficient, but the same idea. I was just staring at the damn thing, and it was like a "duh" moment... like jeez why didn't I see that earlier. ;)